# Crear fechas aleatorias en Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, postgresql-12

necesito crear una función en **postgres** que me devuelva una **fecha** de tipo de dato `date` entre cierto intervalo de tiempo para poder insertar varios registros, por ejemplo:

```
Una fecha entre el 01/01/2019 al 31/12/2019.
```

La verdad soy nuevo en este aspecto y no he encontrado mucho en internet sobre esto, así que cualquier tipo de ayuda está bien.

Answer (score 0):

## Random()

Puedes usar la función `random()` para generar un decimal y usarlo para "aleatorizar" una fecha o un timestamp:

```
    Select (
        Select 
            timestamp '2019-12-31 23:59:59' + 
            random() * (timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:01' - timestamp '2019-12-31 23:59:59')
            )::date As fecha_random;
```

Usando en el resultado una suma de una fecha negativa obtenemos una fecha aleatoria dentro del rango que le pongamos.

[Función Random](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/random.php)